# R programming loop

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I am just starting the R program. I have couple of questions.
I want to create for loop. For example; I created like this. But I want to, loop created every x value,

```
result = result + 2*n+1 
for x = -1 result = 0
for x = 0 result = 0
for x = 1 result = 3
for x = 2 result = 6
# etc, until
x = 9 result = 27


result = 0
vector<-c(-1:9)
for (x in vector){
  print(x)
  x = x+1
  n = as.integer(1)
  if (x<=0){
    result= 1
  } else{
    result = result + 2*n+1
  }
}
print(result)
```

Comment: result = result + 2*n+1 
    for x = -1 result = 0
    for x = 0 result = 0
    for x = 1 result = 3
    for x = 2 result = 6....
    until x = 9 result = 27   This is just example; I want to do like this.

Comment: If `x == 0`, `2*x+1` is not `0`. Why do you want that result? Is it a typo in the question?

Comment: Actually, I want to if x<=0 result = 1, if x>0 result = 2*n+1

Comment: So for `x == 9` it's `result == 2*9 + 1 == 19`?

Comment: No. Like a summation problem. x ==9 result = 9*(2*n+1)==27

Comment: What is `n` then? There is no `n` in the question, it's undefined.

Comment: n == 1. n is constant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this it? The special cases for `x <= 0` force the code to predict the special case when `x` already is above `0`, meaning, `x == 1`.

```
n <- 1
vector <- -1:9
for (x in vector){
  cat("x:", x, "\t")
  if (x <= 0){
    result <- 1
  } else{
    if(x == 1) result <- 0
    result <- result + 2*n + 1
  }
  cat("result:", result, "\n")
}
#x: -1  result: 1 
#x: 0   result: 1 
#x: 1   result: 3 
#x: 2   result: 6 
#x: 3   result: 9 
#x: 4   result: 12 
#x: 5   result: 15 
#x: 6   result: 18 
#x: 7   result: 21 
#x: 8   result: 24 
#x: 9   result: 27
```

Comment: Yes, its true. Thank you so much. I understand now. But ı have a question. How did you increase x. On which line?

Comment: @syurtekin On the line `for (x in vector){`. `x` will take each of the values of `vector`, one per loop iteration.

Comment: I see. I understand now. Thank you so much.